# How to check current URL for endpoint in a template file?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, author

What's the best way to check current url for endpoint in a template file? I have a plugin that creates endpoints in **author.php**... so now i'm trying to check in **author.php** so that only certain code is executed if the URL ends in a specific endpoint?

`example.com/author/username/endpointA`

`example.com/author/username/endpointB`

The idea is that each endpoint has different content.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this tutorial for query variables: http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/.

Essentially what you will be adding is a custom query variable with value either A or B to show different content. I.e. /author/username/contentA is actually index.php?author=username&customqueryvar=contentA.

Comment: Looks promising, i'm currently using this code: https://gist.github.com/705545 Any idea if there is anything in there that I can call in my template? The example you linked to uses "query_vars" to set custom variable, but i don't see that here.

Comment: Ah no - different solution, I've never seen that one before - query var is pretty straightforward, but it depends what you need to do. If it is just the A/B and you can't get the other working give it a go.

Comment: Or use ```get_query_var( 'endpoint', false ) !== false```